# Graphviz, horizontal edges

Tags: graphviz

I can't find the right way to create horizontal edges between nodes.

I would like in one line nodes for example a, b, c. But each node have many other ways to other nodes and this nodes aren't in same height.

I generate graph with *"rankdir=LR;"*

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "drawing with constrained ranks" in the [user guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dot.1.pdf) for "dot".

> In graphs with time-lines, or in drawings that emphasize source and
>   sink nodes, you may need to constrain rank assignments. The rank of a
>   subgraph may be set to same, min, source, max or sink. A value same
>   causes all the nodes in the subgraph to occur on the same rank.

example

```
{ rank = same; 1980; "build"; "emacs"; "vi"; }
{ rank = same; 1982; "RCS"; "<curses>"; "IMX"; "SYNED"; }
```